# Multilevel site zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

in my site i need process the following urls:

http://localhost/groups/{id_group}

localhost/groups/{id_group}/events

localhost/groups/{id_group}/events/{id_event}

localhost/groups/{id_group}/events/{id_event}/galery

localhost/groups/{id_group}/events/{id_event}/galery/{id_galery}/{id_photo}

localhost/groups/{id_group}/events/{id_event}/notes/{id_note}

I created the following structure:

application/

application/groups/

application/groups/controllers

application/groups/controllers/GroupController.php

application/groups/controllers/GroupEventsController.php

application/groups/controllers/GroupEventsGaleryController.php

application/groups/controllers/GroupEventsNotesController.php

Is this the right way to do it?. The main problem I have is that in each of these controllers i need access to data of the group and would be repeating code in all controllers. For example in the controller GroupEventsGaleryController and GroupEventsNotesController i need group's data and event. I dontknow how to do this well.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the IDs via GET anyway, I presume. I'd do it this way:

```
modules
  --group
    --controllers
      IndexController.php
      EventController.php
      GalleryController.php
      NoteController.php
    --views
      --scripts
        --index
          index.phtml
          ...
        --event
          index.phtml
          ...
        --gallery
          index.phtml
          ...
        --note
          index.phtml
          ...
```

(this doesn't mean your structure isn't going to work, I just find this clearer).

Then you can write a custom router that will structure your URLs the way you propose.